# Slow mysql query on large table

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, innodb

I have a statistics table with ~600k records in it, on which i perform the following (raw sql) query to get statistical data for a graph:

```
SELECT 
(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(s.date)*1000+3600000) as time,
ROUND((s.loadtime / s.loadtimeMeasurements), 3) as loadtime 
FROM mw_statistics s 
WHERE s.type = 0 
    AND s.date >= '2013-02-01 07:52:06' 
    AND s.date <= '2013-02-01 11:52:06' 
    AND s.product_id IN (1,8,9,10,11) 
GROUP BY s.date
```

This query takes approximately 1 second to complete. I would like it to take just few hundred ms. Any idea how i might improve this query? I am using Symfony2/Doctrine with a mysql database and innodb engine.

Regards, Jasper

Here's a structure dump of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mw_statistics` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`contentErrors` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`contentMeasurements` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`thirdpartyErrors` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`thirdpartyMeasurements` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`applicationErrors` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`applicationMeasurements` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`loadtime` double NOT NULL,
`loadtimeMeasurements` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
`unavailable` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`unavailableMeasurements` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`type` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
`step` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`date` datetime NOT NULL,
`status` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`script_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `IDX_FC665E6F4584665A` (`product_id`),
KEY `IDX_FC665E6FA1C01850` (`script_id`),
KEY `date` (`date`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
  CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=2105417 ;
```

Notice that the combined is unique: (type=0, product_id, date) or (type=1, script_id, step, date)

Answer (score 0):

Create index for date & id. In where condition put `AND p.id IN (1,8,9,10,11)` after `s.type = 0` i hope it should make your query faster than previous.

Answer (score 0):

To be completely sure of the reasons, I'd need the execution plan (obtained with `EXPLAIN`).

In a pinch, I'd guess there's one or more full table scans involved, due to improper/missing indexes.

You want an INDEX on `mw_statistics` based on `type, date, product_id` in this order:

```
 CREATE INDEX mw_ndx ON mw_statistics ( type, date, product_id )
```

You could also try moving the condition on `p.id` to `s`:

```
WHERE s.type = 0
    AND s.date >= '2013-02-01 06:12:32' AND s.date <= '2013-02-01 10:12:30'
    AND s.product_id IN (1,8,9,10,11)
```

...in which case your index would probably perform better like this:

```
 CREATE INDEX mw_ndx ON mw_statistics ( type, product_id, date )
```

## A closer look

You have a column called `date`, yet you range it using a `datetime`, and group on it, *without any aggregate functions*. It might be the case that you always want to query *a single day*, and the `GROUP BY` is then superfluous. If the column held a `datetime`, you would have very granular (probably useless) groups of very few items, in most cases a single one.

Then, all the data you're loading in comes from the `s` table. You might be better served by implementing constraints on `product_id` to make sure that statistics do have a product and the latter does have a brand.

You could also check beforehand whether the product_ids are legit in this regard. When this is done, your query boils down to

```
SELECT 
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)*1000+3600000) as time,
    ROUND((loadtime / loadtimeMeasurements), 3) as loadtime
FROM mw_statistics
WHERE type = 0
    AND product_id IN (1,8,9,10,11)
    AND date BETWEEN '2013-02-01 06:12:32' AND '2013-02-01 10:12:30'
;
```

which, indexed on `type`, `product_id` and `date`, ought to run in *tens* of milliseconds.

## Specific attempt

```
CREATE INDEX mw_ndx ON mw_statistics (
          type, product_id, date, loadtime, loadtimeMeasurements
     );

SELECT
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)*1000+3600000) as time,
    ROUND((loadtime / loadtimeMeasurements), 3) as loadtime
FROM mw_statistics
WHERE type = 0
  AND product_id IN (1,8,9,10,11)
  AND date BETWEEN '2013-02-01 06:12:32' AND '2013-02-01 10:12:30'
;
```

This way, the necessary records are quickly whittled down by exact selection on `type` and set selection on `product_id`. The `date` selection also ought to perform well; in another situation you might want to consider partitioning or sharding, but with less than a few million records it just doesn't smell worthwhile. Every index entry is weighed with two `smallint`s, but by accepting this small overhead, you actually *never access the main table at all*.

Query runtime will depend on column cardinality; but on a sample, evenly (actually *randomly*) populated sample table with one million rows, I'm getting round-trip times between 8 and 90 milliseconds, depending on cache performances and number of rows actually retrieved.

For a more precise tuning I'd need the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP...`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i updated the question with a table structure and some notes on the "unique" fields. Any suggestion for a (better) index?

Comment: Yes, try the 'specific attempt' recipe. Create the index and run the query, see how it goes.

Comment: You'll have to edit it into the question, it's probably too long as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far.. But could you rewrite the index? I have queries for loadtime, but also for the other 'statistics' like content(Errors), application(Errors), etc. So i guess an index on loadtime won't work? 

Explain now says: |  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | range | IDX_FC665E6FA1C01850,mw_ndx | IDX_FC665E6FA1C01850 | 5       | NULL | 31600 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |

Please notice that the combined is unique: (type=0, product_id, date) or (type=1, script_id, step, date), but the other fields are not

Comment: The index on `loadtime` would, of course, only cover the queries with `loadtime`. But to have indexes for all fields would, overall, cost the same as not having cover indexes at all. I'd suggest checking what query is the most used, and what `WHERE` columns are the more often used, and build one or two indexes accordingly. Better one index with two fields, helping maybe three queries, than one index with three fields that would help more -- but one query only. You need performance statistics to help you decide.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to join with mw_brands? You're not using any data from it, so the only use right now is to make sure that the mw_statistics is related (through mw_products) to a mw_brands?

If you don't need it, remove both joins and change out p.id in (1,8,9,10,11) for s.product_id in (1,8,9,10,11).

Comment: Ah.. stupid, those joins were totally unnecessary! I rewrote it to:

SELECT 
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(s.date)*1000+(3600000)) as time, 
    ROUND((s.loadtime / s.loadtimeMeasurements), 3) as loadtime 
FROM mw_statistics s 
WHERE s.type = 1 
    AND s.date >= '2013-02-01 07:52:05' 
    AND s.date <= '2013-02-01 11:52:05' 
    AND s.product_id IN (1,8,9,10,11) 
GROUP BY s.date

However, it still takes ~1 seconds to complete. I also added an index on "date", but the field isn't unique. The table has statistic records on a date per type/script_id or type/product_id combination.
Any more suggestions?